# p5.js rotateX doesn't work with TriangleStrip?

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I am trying to make a little animation with p5.js in Javascript.

However, I have some issues with the `rotateX()` function. I have the following code:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JbZdRN?editors=1010

```
var w, h, scl, rows, cols;

function setup() {
    w = 500;
    h = 500;
    scl = 20;
    cols = w / scl;
    rows = h / scl;
    createCanvas(500, 500);
}

function draw() {
    background(0);
    noFill();
    stroke(255);
    translate(width/2, height/2);
    rotateX(radians(15));

    for(var y = 0; y < cols; y++) {
        beginShape(TRIANGLE_STRIP);
        for(var x = 0; x < rows; x++){
            vertex(x*scl, y*scl, 0);
            vertex(x*scl, (y+1)*scl, 0);
        }
        endShape();
    }
}
```

The problem is that I cannot rotate the triangle strip on the x-axis.

The thing is, if I use `rotate()` it works (but it's the wrong axis). If I use `rotate(PI, X)` or `rotate(PI, Y)`, it doesn't work either.

So I really can't rotate the whole thing on the X-axis. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Questions like these are best answered by the JavaScript console. Press `F12` in most browsers, or look for "developer options" in your settings menu. Any errors you get go here, and that will help you understand what's happening when things don't work.

In your case, you get an error: `Uncaught not supported in p2d. Please use webgl mode`

And that error tells you everything. You're using the default renderer, which only renders in 2D. Rotating around the X axis requires rendering in 3D. So to fix this error, you need to use the WEBGL renderer by passing it into the `createCanvas()` renderer. More info can be found in [the reference](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/createCanvas).

After you fix that error you have other problems that seem to be related to [this issue](https://github.com/processing/p5.js/issues/1678), but hopefully this gets you going in the right direction. Moral of the story: check the JavaScript console.